# JavaScript - If radio button is checked, change background color

Tags: javascript, php

I am fairly new to JavaScript, and I want to learn some of that before I go to jQuery, so jQuery is no option here.

I have a form where I can write an article, and I've got everything up and running and it works pretty well. The image selector itself works, but it's the looks I want fixed so I don't have to look at the ugly radio buttons under the images, so the radio buttons will be removed, and instead of that, the background of the image gets red or some other obvious colour.

The code that shows the images is like this, it works, except for the onlclick:

```
$dir = 'img/uploads/';

$images = glob($dir.'*.jpg');

$numPics = count($images) / 2 - 1;

for($i = 0; $i<=$numPics; $i++){

    if(strpos($images[$i], 'large')){

?>

<td>

    <label for="selectImage<?=$i; ?>">
        <img src="<?=$images[$i];?>" alt="<?=$images[$i]; ?>" width="250" id="imageLabel<?=$i; ?>">
    </label>

    <input type="radio" name="img" value="<?=$images[$i]; ?>" role="button" id="selectImage<?=$i; ?>" onclick="changeBackground('imageLabel<?=$i; ?>', 'selectImage<?=$i; ?>')">

</td>
<?php

    if($i == 3){

        echo "</tr>";

    }

   }

}
```

The javascript is like this:

```
function changeBackground(id, id2){

    if(document.getElementById(id2).checked == true;) {

        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = 'red';

    }

}
```

What I want is when I check the radio button, the background image on the image changes color, and when I check an other image, it should change the background color on that one. Any idea how I can do this?
The radio buttons will have a display: none; which no problem to do.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My personal opinion is that especially *because* you're a JavaScript novice, jQuery would be good for you. jQuery is 100% JavaScript, it just helps you with several shortcuts.

Comment: @lxg jQuery isn't going to help him with the two things he really needed here. That's not putting a semi-colon in an if condition (it happens sometimes, and can be a pain in the ass to spot) and using his browser's developer tools to check for syntax errors.

Comment: When posting a JavaScript question  please post HTML, even though the PHP *generates* the HTML (that your browser gets), the PHP is irrelevant once the browser - in which the JavaScript runs - has received the HTML.

Comment: Well, I hadn't seen that semicolon, but it still doesn't really do what I want. It's in the right direction, but still not there. It adds a background colour to everything I check, but what I have checked in the past stays with a background-color: red; even when it is not checked.

Comment: *"even when it is not checked"* Well you do not tell it to go back.

Comment: Figured, but I have no idea how to do that in javascript. I'm a terrible person when it comes to javascript.

Comment: Well you use a "change" event and not click. You add an else and set the color to the default color.

Comment: That's noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reality you need ZERO JavaScript to do it.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;  
}
input[type="radio"] + label {
    background-color: yellow;  
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background-color: lime;  
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r1"><label for="r1">One</label>
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r2"><label for="r2">Two</label>
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r3"><label for="r3">Three</label>
<input type="radio" name="r" id="r4"><label for="r4">Four</label>
```

For your problem, if you opened up the JavaScript console in the developer tools you would have seen an error message `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` or something similar which would point to the randomly placed semicolon in the if statement. Next issue with your code is you do not switch the color back when the checkbox is unchecked, so if the user picks a different option, it will still be green.

Comment: Well, the OP needs "*zero JavaScript to do it*" if s/he can, and is able to, re-structure the HTML, which isn't always applicable. But yes, CSS is often the better choice for this sort of thing.

Comment: Okay, this one here works way better than the javascript thing I had in mind. I'll use this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
function changeBackground(id, id2){

  if(document.getElementById(id2).checked) {

    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = 'red';

  }
}
```

You had a semicolon in your condition which breaks the whole thing.

Comment: Not probably, definitely. With that randomly placed semi-colon you get a syntax error.